# What are some examples of genuine Hindu names that include the alphabets X and Z?

Tags: name

I am working on an ML algorithm to predict the most likely religion of a person based on the names. For example the algorithm would predict Deepika Patel as a Hindu/Jain, Deepika Kaur as a Sikh, Deepika Geroge as a Christian and Daleela Patel as a Muslim. For training this algorithm, I am looking for specific examples of counter examples. I observed that most of the Hindu names rarely include the alphabets `X` and `Z`. But there few counter examples such as Gulzarilal which a Hindu firstname and Zakaria which I know personally is a Brahmin surname. Internet search such as [the ones in this link](https://nriol.com/babynames/gzz.asp) show several Hindu names with the alphabet `Z` but I am not sure how reliable this information is.

**Question**: What are some examples of genuine Hindu names that include the alphabets `X` and `Z`?

Comment: I suggest not taking names from baby name websites.

Comment: sanskrit doesn't contain z, so any name containing z will be apbhransh of sanskrit name or be related to urdu. Many people like laxmi instead of lakshmi so that can be used. Also Zakaria is of arabic origin

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow There are Brahmins with surname Zakaria who have nothing to do with Arabs. Its just a co-incidence that they could Arabs with that name

Comment: Are they from maharashtra from any chance as don't know any such name from the ganga basin

Comment: Assam, Brahmaputra basin

Comment: Do they say that as Shakaria? As in assam the language is similar to bengali

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Hazarika another example of a Hindu name which has a Z. Example = famous singer Late Bhupen Hazarika. Co-incidentally he is also from Assam

Comment: Z doesn't exist in Sanskrit. A person named Michael can still follow Hindu customs and rituals if he wants, and call himself a Hindu.

Comment: @mar  That is no longer relevant in 2022. Eg. Hazarika is a kshatria community. They have normal hindu first names and Hazarika as their surname. Also my question is about Hindus of today rather than as per the sanskrit scriptures

Comment: Thenmozhi is a Tamil Hindu name , Any name that has the equivalent sound of  Tamil 'ழ'  will be replaced with 'zha'. See the following  YouTube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L65AGKOxUM>